# Is there any other built-in cumulative function like cumsum & cumprod in matlab?

Tags: matlab

For example, I want generate a vector ys from xs by:

```
ys(1) = xs(1)
ys(2) = max(xs(1:2))
ys(k) = max(xs(1:k))
ys(n) = max(xs)
```

Generally, given a vector xs and a function f, Is there any built-in function to give ys as:

```
ys(1) = f(xs(1))
ys(k) = f(xs(1:k))
```

EDIT: I just find out that I can use arrayfun like:

```
ys = arrayfun(@(k) f(xs(1:k)),1:size(xs,2))
```

EDIT2: I still want to know if there is some built-in function like 'cumarray' can be used as:

```
ys = cumarray(xs,f)
```

Comment: add the answer as, well.. 'an answer' below and mark it as solved after 2 days

Comment: the function name is `accumarray` (I can't edit since it's only a 2 letters change)

Comment: @carandraug I already known the function, but I have no idea how this function to be using as ys = cumarray(xs,f) and getting the result I wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Matlab I believe the only other one is `cumtrapz()`.

In Octave there is also `cummax()` and `cummin()`. There's also `accumdim()` which behaves like `accumarray()` but along a specified dimension.